# Why the IF condition gets FALSE even though the complete DS is blank?

Tags: rpgle

Here's a test source where I need to ID and validate the (fixed) *blank positions in a fixed-len string, *data*. So here the first blank_string is of char(4) starting pos(2), and the second blank_string is of char(2) starting pos(8) declared as a *source* DS

```
dcl-s data char(12) inz('z    zz  zzz');    
                                            
// '1234+6789112'                           
// 'z....zz..zzz'                           
                                            
dcl-ds source inz;                
  *n char(4) pos(2); //will be usually blank
  *n char(2) pos(8); //will be usually blank
end-ds;                                     
                                            
source = data;                              
                                            
//check if the DS is blank                  
if source = *blanks;                        
  dsply 'DS is surely blank';                      
endif;
```

looking in debugger, the DS appears as expected, i.e. all blank.
[image: debugger op]

Even though the DS is as clean as a glass, yet the IF condition is set to FALSE, and exits without executing the dsply.

EDIT: summarizing compiler's POV

```
//structure user trying to define

dcl-ds source inz;
  *n char(4) pos(2); //will be usually blank
  *n char(2) pos(8); //will be usually blank
end-ds;

//structure that actually got defined

dcl-ds source inz;                
  *n char(1) pos(1);
  *n char(4) pos(2); //will be usually blank
  *n char(2) pos(6);
  *n char(2) pos(8); //will be usually blank
end-ds;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `source` isn't blank.  `source` contains `'z    zz  '` as you copied `data` to `source`.

Just because the debugger by default is showing you the defined sub-fields of `source` doesn't make that all that is in `source`.

try this
`eval source:c 9`

Which instructs the debugger to display source as a char(9) variable.

Comment: Whoa, that's weird. 
And how come the DS got the length of 9 bytes???

Comment: Because the last field is char(2) and starts at pos(8), that is it uses positions 8 and 9.

Comment: I fail to see what is weird about this. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: Thank you, Charles and Mark, for your explanations. It is counterintuitive to me as during IF comparison, I expected it to comply to the DS declaration i.e. drop every other positions/lengths but the ones defining the very structure (apparently, the debugger seemed closer to the idea of the Data-Structure)

Comment: RPG considers the data structure itself to also be a character field. Even if the data structure has numeric or date subfields, when you do an operation with the data structure name, it is considered to be a character field.

Answer (score 0):

The RPG compiler treats a structure as a string within which you lay out individual fields.
In your case it is a 9 character long string.
When declaring, the structure is automatically initialized with the default value for the given type (string) - it is filled with spaces.
After you have assigned

```
source = data;
```

your string is no longer empty but contains a value

```
'z    zz  '
```

the fields you marked up will still be empty, but what is between them is not empty.

Accordingly, the condition

```
if source = *blanks;
```

is not true.